# Extract name of a subdirectory from a path

Tags: regex, bash, path

I would like to extract the subdirectory name using a bash script from a path like `/home/user1/subdir/foo_1/foo_2/.../foo_n`.
`subdir` will always reside under `/home/user1` hence the prefix is invariant but there can be varied number of subdirectories under `subdir`

Some examples:

- /home/user1/dir1/something/like/this: RESULT: dir1
- /home/user1/dir2/different/this/time/: RESULT: dir2
- /home/user1/dir3/this/is/the/last/example: RESULT: dir3

I wrote this regex but it doesn't work correctly:

```
 expr /home/user1/subdir/foo_1/foo_2 : '\/home\/user1\/\(.*\/\)\{1\}'
```

, but it seems to give `subdir/foo_1` instead of `subdir`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that matching is done in a greedy manner. `.*` will match as much as it can, which in your case means it will match more than one slash, when you really wanted it to stop at the first slash.

You should specifically match everything after `/home/user1/` but before the next `/`

```
expr /home/user1/subdir/foo_1/foo_2 : '\/home\/user1\/\([^\/]*\)'
```

which outputs:

```
subdir
```

Comment: Why will `.*\/` match more than one slash? I have added `{1}` post that expression. Your solutions works, but I am not able to get my head around why my regex is failing. Thanks @Anson

Comment: `.*` will always match as many characters as possible (greedy matching). It'll match any and all characters, including slashes. So in the string `subdir/foo_1/foo_2`, `.*/` will match `subdir/foo_1/`. Your `{1}` modifier has no effect on how much `.*` will match. `{n}` just means that whatever was matched in the preceding expression should be repeated n times. In fact, the `{1}` modifier is unnecessary here for the reason I just stated; I edited my answer and removed it.

Answer (score 2):

```
(?<=/home/user1/)[^/]+(?=/)
```

test:

```
kent$  echo "/home/user1/dir1/something/like/this"|grep -oP "(?<=/home/user1/)[^/]+(?=/)"
dir1
```

Comment: The look-ahead part isn't necessary: the matching will naturally end at a slash.

Answer (score 2):

The shell can do this by itself if you can spend a temporary variable.

```
t=${path#/home/user1/}
subdir=${t%/*}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dir=/home/user1/subdir/foo_1/foo_2/.../foo_n
sub=$( IFS=/; set -- $dir; echo $4 )
echo $sub   # => subdir
```